# Azure Machine Learning Studio : Deployed Service gives OutOfMemoryLimit exception

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-machine-learning-service

Using Azure Machine Learning Studio I have published a few models that are having OutOfMemoryLimit issues in the deployed services (not during training).

The model type I am using is the "multiclass decision forest", and I do create some decent sized forests. When stored to a blob they take up to around 150 MB in size. Closing in on 150 I get OOM every time. At around 140 Maybe 1 in 10, and even at 120 MB they happens now and then.

The thing is it runs fine in the studio, and when deployed as a service it is not very consistent in when it gives exceptions. I can run requests against a service and get a reply 9 out of 10 cases, but then in the 10% remaining cases I will get an exception that looks like this:

> {"error":{"code":"MemoryQuotaViolation","message":"The model had
>   exceeded the memory quota assigned to
>   it.","details":[{"code":"OutOfMemoryLimit","message":"The model
>   consumed more memory than was appropriated for it. Maximum allowed
>   memory for the model is 2560 MB. Please check your model for
>   issues."}]}}

Now I do run this as a request-response, as opposed to a batch job, and I suspect it might do just fine as a batch job. The reason for R-R is that I do need these data in real time and batch jobs are simply too slow.

I suspect the "right" approach is to further handicap my forest by reducing tree count or increasing leaf node sizes, but obviously this will reduce the model accuracy (further). Before I do so I am looking for some advice around:

Is it possible to pay for MORE than the 2,5 GB limit for the Azure ML SaaS ? (If not when is that coming??)

Is there any way to test whether a deployed model will break this limit or not before actually deploying it? We are trying to run retraining automatically and this reduces our reliability drastically.

Any other advice on what to try/test/think of

Thanks in advance!